# Booting from usb in ubuntu on macbook

Tags: boot, usb, windows, macosx

Ive installed ubuntu solely on my macbook. However, I want to change to windows. I try to open the startup manager by pressing option(alt) on the macbook. However, no options appear. If osx is installed then osx, USB, and internet recovery options will appear. Obviously OSX will not appear anymore.

Does anyone know how to get the USB boot option? (apart from internet recovery to OSX then to windows through OSX)

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from a USB device pressing the "c" key at boot time.

[Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)

Comment: soz thats what i meant, when i press C to enter startup manager, i dont get the option to boot from usb (or anything else apart from internet recovery) :(